# How can I randomly draw a set of parameters from a regression given a model fit and covariance matrix?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, least-squares, covariance, statsmodels

I have built a GLM and have the fitted parameters and covariance matrix. I'd like to generate a set of random beta-parameters using the covariance matrix to estimate what the confidence bounds and prediction intervals of different segments of the model and data.

My rough understanding is that this can be done by using the Cholesky decomposition of the correlation matrix and then combined somehow with the beta parameters, but I'm not sure what's next. Most of my reading on the Cholesky decomposition indicates that this is used to generate random *data*, not random *parameters*.

For clarity, given the following, how can I generate a set of beta parameters that will produce a distribution of responses for different volumes of data (single observation, 10 observations, 100's of observations).

```py
from statsmodels.api import GLM, families
from numpy import array

X = array([[1,4,1],  [1,4,0],  [1,0,3],  [1,0,0],  [1,1,0]])
y = array([10,1,1,1,10])
model = GLM(y, X, family=families.Tweedie()).fit()

# Imaginary function would go here.
model.display_distribution_of_prediction(n=1)
## shows density plot of single observation

model.display_distribution_of_prediction(n=1000)
## shows density plot of 1000 observations
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Your title says 'regression' but your body text says 'GLM'. It would be better if the title and body were consistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GLM theory states that the parameters have asymptotic normal distribution.  Plug in the estimates and the covariance like so...

```py
from statsmodels.api import GLM, families
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

X = np.array([[1,4,1],  [1,4,0],  [1,0,3],  [1,0,0],  [1,1,0]])
y = np.array([10,1,1,1,10])
model = GLM(y, X, family=families.Tweedie()).fit()

beta = model.params
sigma = model.cov_params()

B = np.random.multivariate_normal(beta, sigma, size = 1000)

sns.pairplot(pd.DataFrame(B))
```

[image]

Comment: What does *GLM theory states...* mean? The maximum likelihood estimates of these parameters are asymptotically normally distributed

Comment: Yes, I’m being a little imprecise in the name of being terse.

Comment: Should random draws from the actual response give identical distributions to random draws generated using scores resulting from simulated beta's on the input data?

Comment: @joe I'm not sure I quite understand.  Can you open another question and provide some details?